# Sort array by two object properties using anonymous function

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 1
            [id] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 123
            [id] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 123
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

I'm currently using the following code to sort the array by the timestamp property:

```
function sort_comments_by_timestamp(&$comments, $prop)
{
    usort($comments, function($a, $b) use ($prop) {
        return $a->$prop < $b->$prop ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

How can I also sort id by `id` descending when timestamp is the same?

Comment: Is there a reason why you call it `_by_timestamp`, but also have a `$prop` parameter?

Comment: @Matthew other than `I was doing some tests` and bad naming? No :) Already fixed it btw

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Suggestion is to send in an array with $props

```
function sort_comments_by_timestamp(&$comments, $props)
{
    usort($comments, function($a, $b) use ($props) {
        if($a->$props[0] == $b->$props[0])
            return $a->$props[1] < $b->$props[1] ? 1 : -1;
        return $a->$props[0] < $b->$props[0] ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

And then call it with

```
sort_comments_by_timestamp($unsorted_array,array("timestamp","id"));
```

If you want it to work with X number of $props you can make a loop inside the usort always comparing a property with its preceding property in the array like this:

```
function sort_comments_by_timestamp(&$comments, $props)
{
    usort($comments, function($a, $b) use ($props) {
        for($i = 1; $i < count($props); $i++) {
            if($a->$props[$i-1] == $b->$props[$i-1])
                return $a->$props[$i] < $b->$props[$i] ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return $a->$props[0] < $b->$props[0] ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: If you get error: `Array to string conversion` you need to replace all `$a->$props[X]` to `$a->{$props[X]}`

Answer (score 4):

```
function sort_comments_by_timestamp(&$comments, $prop)
{
    usort($comments, function($a, $b) use ($prop) {
        if ($a->$prop == $b->$prop)
          return $b->id - $a->id;
        else
          return $a->$prop < $b->$prop ? 1 : -1;
    });
}
```

The above sorts first by the `$prop` parameter and then secondary by `id`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies) (I know you've heard about it :P).

```
$result = Arrays::sort($array,
    Comparator::compound(
        Comparator::compareBy('timestamp'),
        Comparator::compareBy('id')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is fairly old question however didn't find much info for when you want to sort by multiple properties kinda like mySQL **ORDERBY** does so here's a function from a personal framework

Option 1: order(**$key, $direction='asc'**) where $key is a property of the objects and $direction is 'asc' or 'desc'

Option 2: order(**array($key => $direction, $key => $direction)**)
This is similar to option 1 however when 2 objects have the same value for $key, the second sort option from the array passed is used.

```
public function order($arr, $key=null, $direction='ASC'){
    if(!is_string($key) && !is_array($key))
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("order() expects the first parameter to be a valid key or array");

    $props = array();

    if(is_string($key)) {
        $props[$key] = strtolower($direction) == 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    }else{
        $i = count($key);
        foreach($key as $k => $dir){
            $props[$k] = strtolower($dir) == 'asc' ? $i : -($i);
            $i--;
        }
    }

    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use ($props){
        foreach( $props as $key => $val ){
            if( $a->$key == $b->$key ) continue;
            return $a->$key > $b->$key ? $val : -($val);
        }
        return 0;
    });

    return $arr;

}
```

Comment: Very nice little function. I was using the accepted answer for my sorting needs (with some personal tweaks) and it decided to stop working after a CMS update of the website. This saved me a bunch of time trying to debug what the problem is/was.

Comment: Glad it helped out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = -1;
if ($a->timestamp < $b->timestamp) {
   $result = 1;
} else if ($a->timestamp === $b->timestamp) {
   if ($a->id < $b->id) $result = 1;
}
return $result;
```

Put this within the usort closure. You can also get rid of the $prop argument and the `use ($prop)` part.

Answer (score 2):

```
      function compare_city($a, $b)
      {
        // sort by state
        $retval = strnatcmp($a->state, $b->state);
        // if identical, sort by city
        if(!$retval) $retval = strnatcmp($a->city, $b->city);
        return $retval;
      }

      // sort alphabetically by state and city
      usort($sortable, __NAMESPACE__ . '\compare_city');
```

This function worked with me! Answer found at: [*Sorting SimpleXMLElement Object arrays*](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/sort-simplexml/)

Comment: A number of the answers above (including the accepted answer!) seem to miss the 'equal' outcome for comparisons. Nice to see use of `strnatcmp` to handle this properly, in particular for string properties. Also don't forget `strnatcasecmp` for the case insensitive equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer has a loop variant that will not always work.

```
if($a->$props[$i-1] == $b->$props[$i-1])
     return $a->$props[$i] < $b->$props[$i] ? 1 : -1;
```

obj1 prop1:foo, prop2: bar, prop3: test

obj2 prop1:foo, prop2: bar, prop3: apple

At $i = 1, the first comparison is true, and as bar is not less than bar, it will return -1 rather than continue with the loop to evaluate prop3.

Just an FYI.

I have a variant that also takes direction, so each property can also be sorted by ascending or descending order using -1 and 1, respectively.

```
function sortByProps(&$anArray, $props) {
    usort($anArray, function($a, $b) use ($props) {
        for($i = 0; $i < count($props); $i++) {
            if( $a->{$props[$i][0]} < $b->{$props[$i][0]}) {
                return $props[$i][1];
            }
            else if( $a->{$props[$i][0]} > $b->{$props[$i][0]}) {
                return -1* $props[$i][1];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

sortByProps($someArray,(array(['name',-1],['address',-1],['occupation',-1],['favorite_food',-1])));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to sort by an arbitrary number of criteria, one after the other, breaking ties. It works a lot like an sql `order by col1, col2` clause.

I always forget if `$a - $b` vs `$b - $a` sorts ascending or descending. Adjust as needed.

```
$comparatorSequence = array(
    function($a, $b) { return $a->timestamp - $b->timestamp; }
  , function($a, $b) { return $a->id - $b->id; }
);

usort($theArray, function($a, $b) use ($comparatorSequence) {
    foreach ($comparatorSequence as $cmpFn) {
        $diff = call_user_func($cmpFn, $a, $b);
        if ($diff !== 0) {
            return $diff;
        }
    }
    return 0;
});
```